# writing a pattern recognition 'function to find occurrence of numbers in specific order? c++

Tags: c++

i have a container which stores double values from a source, and i need to find  the location of numbers when it appears in a specific order/pattern.

```
vector<double> m = {-0.15,0.2,-0.2,-0.1,0.5,-0.15,-0.8,0.35,-0.2,-0.35......nth}
```

is there any way to find the location of numbers, if the appear in a order(in sequence) like:

```
m[x] = 0.1 to 0.5  //value of m[x] must between those two values
m[x+1] = 0.35 to 0.7 //anywhere between the range 
m[x+2] = -0.1 to 0.1 //         "     
m[x+3] = 0.0 to.03    //        "
```

Comment: You can just do [naive string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Na%C3%AFve_string_search) but rather than checking for equality between characters, check for inequalities between doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) with a custom predicate.

Your pattern would contain ranges, and you need a custom binary predicate returning true if the LHS double lies in the RHS range.

Un-tested example:

```
using Range = std::pair<double,double>;
std::vector<Range> pattern {{0.1, 0.5}, {0.35, 0.7}, {-0.1, 0.1}, {0.0, 0.03}};
auto match = std::search(begin(m), end(m),
                         begin(pattern), end(pattern),
                         [](double d, Range r) {
                           return (r.first < d) && (d < r.second);
                         });
```

Add appropriate epsilon for your double comparisons, etc. etc.

Comment: thank you for helping me , but i'm facing some problem with this, my problem is that this function only finds the first occurrence of pattern, what if there is more occurrence later how am I suppose to find the location of succeeding patterns if they occur.

Comment: if `match != end(m)`, just search again starting after that, `auto nextmatch = std::search(match+1, end(m), ...`. It's simpler if you wrap it in a function.